# In python: use xpath with an element from a list

Tags: python, xml, xpath, phylogeny

With the help from several people here at Stackoverflow I came up with the following code:

```
import lxml.etree

f = open("PaVE.tre.xml", "r")
out = open("PaVE.2.xml", "a")
data = f.read()
line=["HPV16","Alpha"]

tree = lxml.etree.XML(data)
nsmap = {'phylo': 'http://www.phyloxml.org'}
matches = tree.xpath('//phylo:name[text()="HPV16"]', namespaces=nsmap)

for e in matches:
    #do something fun
```

However, I am hard-coding the HPV16 into the xpath expression. I would like to take the HPV16 from line[0]. I was thinking something like:

```
matches = tree.xpath('//phylo:name[text()='+line[0]+']', namespaces=nsmap)
```

However, that does not seem to work!
As always, any help would be appreciated

EDIT:
I added a couple of lines from the xml file as was requested:

```
<phyloxml xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.phyloxml.org" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.phyloxml.org http://www.phyloxml.org/1.10/phyloxml.xsd">
<phylogeny rooted="true">
  <clade>
    <clade>
      <branch_length>0.5</branch_length>
      <clade>
        <name>HPV16</name>
        <branch_length>1.0</branch_length>
      </clade>
      <clade>
```

Comment: Can we get an example of the XML?

Comment: You're missing the double quotes around `line[0]` ... `text()="'+line[0]+'"]`

Comment: "that does not seem to work" - what is happening? Exception? Wrong output? Etc. Also, what's the contents of `line[0]`? (p.s. haven't you forgotten the double quotes around it?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot the quotes in your XPath expression:

```
>>> '//phylo:name[text()='+line[0]+']'
'//phylo:name[text()=something]'
```

I would do this instead:

```
>>> '//phylo:name[text()="%s"]' % line[0]
'//phylo:name[text()="something"]'
```

Comment: Can you call `text()` in the predicate? I thought it was a node like any other tag. Could be I'm remembering it wrong, its been a while since I used xpath.

Comment: Thanks guys, I feel so stupid! I should have seen those quotes!